# How does a STUN server know whether short-term or long-term credentials were used for sending the STUN request?

Tags: webrtc, stun

RFC 5389 allows one of two forms of authentication for STUN servers:

```
 ... This section defines two mechanisms for STUN that a client and server
 can use to provide authentication and message integrity; these two
 mechanisms are known as the short-term credential mechanism and the
 long-term credential mechanism.  These two mechanisms are optional,
 and each usage must specify if and when these mechanisms are used.
 Consequently, both clients and servers will know which mechanism (if
 any) to follow based on knowledge of which usage applies.  For
 example, a STUN server on the public Internet supporting ICE would
 have no authentication, whereas the STUN server functionality in an
 agent supporting connectivity checks would utilize short-term credentials.
```

The most popular STUN server is most likely the one available at stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 and clearly does not require any credentials.

iceServers are provided to RTCPeerConnection through objects such as:

```
   myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
         {
              urls: "turn:turnserver.example.org",
              username: "webrtc",
              credential: "turnpassword"
         }
       ]
   });
```

My question is when sending the request to the STUN server, how does ICE processing construct the STUN request? Does it use short-term or long-term credentials? Is the **credentialType** property which I think I have seen to be interpreted as short-term or long-term?  And how does the STUN server know which process (short- or long-term) was followed for creating the message request. Unless it knows that, it cannot authenticate the request, unless the process is the same. In that case, why distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TURN allocations are always done using the long-term credential mechanism, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766#section-2.2

STUN requests to STUN servers typically do not require authentication.

The short-term credentials mechanism is used for other things like ICE, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-4.3

Comment: From the ICE RFC you cited: "The username part of this credential is formed by concatenating a username fragment from each agent, separated by a colon." Presuming that there are two agents involved, the order is important. How is that decided? The controlling agent's username is first? Also, "each agent" connotes the possibility of more than two agents too. I think it should have been "both agents"?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-7.1.2.3
-- this is done on *each* agent, but the local/remote role is different which means the result is different. Presumably that is the reason the spec doesn't use "both agents"

Comment: It is clear in the section of the RFC you have cited. Sorry I should be reading in detail before firing questions.